# I am getting 502 Bad Gateway when I use Proxy

Tags: php, proxy, cpanel, bad-request

I am getting 502 Bad Gateway when I use Proxy/ HotSpotshield. I want to know that which can be involved in this issue. My PHP Script or my server configuration? I am using cPanel Hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1**.Try loading the URL again by pressing F5 on your keyboard, or by clicking the refresh/reload button.

While the 502 Bad Gateway error is usually indicating a networking error outside of your control, it could be extremely temporary. Trying the page again will often be successful.

**2**.Start a new browser session by closing all open browser windows and then opening a new one. Then try opening the webpage again.

It's possible that the 502 error you received was due to an issue on your computer that occurred sometime during this use of your browser. A simple restart of the browser program itself could solve the problem.

**3**.Clear your browser's cache. Outdated or corrupted files that are being stored by your browser could be causing 502 Bad Gateway issues.

**4**.Delete your browser's cookies. For similar reasons as mentioned above with cached files, clearing stored cookies could fix a 502 error.

**5**. Start your browser in Safe Mode. Running a browser in Safe Mode means to run it with default settings and without add-ons or extensions, including toolbars.

If the 502 error no longer appears when running your browser in Safe Mode, you know that some browser extension or setting is the cause of the problem. Return your browser settings to default and/or selectively disable browser extensions to find the root cause and permanently fix the problem.

**6**.Try another browser. Popular browsers include Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer, and Safari, among others.

If an alternative browser doesn't produce a 502 Bad Gateway error, you now know that your original browser is the source of the problem. Assuming you've followed the above troubleshooting advice, now would be the time to reinstall your browser and see if that corrects the problem.

**7**.Restart your computer. Some temporary issues with your computer and how it's connecting to your network could be causing 502 errors, especially if you're seeing the error on more than one website. In these cases, a restart would help.

**8**.Restart your networking equipment. Issues with your modem, router, switches, or other networking devices could be causing Bad Gateway or other 502 errors. A simple restart of these devices could help.

Tip: The order you turn off these devices isn't particularly important, but be sure to turn them back on from the outside in. In other words, turn on the outermost hardware on the network first (usually your modem), followed by the device it's connected to (usually your router). Next would be any switch or other device between the router and your computer.

**9**. Contact the website directly. Chances are, assuming they're at fault, the website administrators are already working on correcting the cause of the 502 Bad Gateway error but feel free to let them know about it, especially if you suspect that they may not be.

The best way to find a website's contact information is usually through a WHOIS search, using the domain name (e.g. cnn.com) as your search term.

If the results of that search doesn't reveal an email address, many websites can be contacted via webmaster@website.com, replacing website.com with the actual website name. Contacting them via their social networking page is another option.

**10**.Contact your Internet Service Provider. If your browser, computer, and network is working, and the website reports that the page or site is working for them, the 502 Bad Gateway issue could be caused by a network issue that your ISP is responsible for.

Hope this points will help you... Good Luck.

Check also, http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/forefront/en-US/1255e9e5-6fc2-4da9-8df6-c41599314f9b/proxy-server-shows-502-bad-gateway?forum=Forefrontedgegeneral

Comment: My question was that which one can be the issue, the server or the script?

Comment: it might be fault in serer configuration.... is it already working on another server or not?

Comment: It is working fine on my normal internet connection. But when I use HotSpotShield or any proxy to access my website. I get 502 error.

Comment: check your configuration in hotspot shield .

Comment: Other websites are working great. I am getting error on my website only.

Comment: This answer is a copy and paste from http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/502error.htm

Comment: @voon- So what is the problem? you know 100% things about your specilaised area? I'll try to help the users by the points from another websites/blogs etc and not only in my knowledge. It is not prevented here and I'm not spamming or misleading here. DONT TRY TO OVER SMART !!!

Comment: @voon - read this -> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226388/adding-points-from-external-source-into-answers-is-good-or-not/226391?noredirect=1#226391

Comment: Because the link I cited is the first one that comes up when I Google "502 bad gateway". Maybe its because I found the original source first, then immediately went to this S.O. question afterwards - So I got the impression that this answer wasn't very useful.